# Android efficient layouting

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm writing an app with a custom theme and `layout` (some CI) for `API 18+`, so I need to align a lot of elements.

I read several times, that one should avoid nested layouts as good as possible, but also that some layout types are less efficient than others (`RelativeLayout`).

- should I still avoid nested views these days?
- if yes, what is more efficient

  - flat `RelativeLayout`
  - nested `LinearLayout` (2 levels)
  - what about `TableLayout` with `TableRows`

Currently I already have this layout hierarchy:

- `Drawer` (for `sidemenu`)

  - `Relative` (because of `header` and `footer`)

    - `Frame` (Content goes below here, just used for easy replacing of fragments)

Comment: It would be great if someone could provide some tests and numbers as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current layout hierarchy is very sample and under normal circumstances it should not be slow at all. Of course the FrameLayout is not needed as you are using a relative layout because your can align the center content below and above the header and footer of the relative layout children.

**For this level of nesting the view there is absolutely no problem as for performance.**

Both RealtiveLayout and LinearLayout extend FrameLayout with relative being a little heavier as it handles what else the relationships between the views.

If you need to align many element (like editexts and textview) in a form-type layout the best option is TableLayout.

General speaking layout inflation from XML is expensive, but nesting a view inside another makes no difference in real life. The problem would be if you had a thousand views in a TableView with TableRows having nested layout inside.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For clarification: 
I use the FrameLayout to insert/replace fragments. 
As far as I understood, I need a ViewGroup to do this.
Having just a container which holds an fragment, makes it easy to replace it in code.